# Some "For purchase" apps not visible in software centre

Tags: 11.04, software-center, paid-applications

I recently read that Uplink was available from Software Centre.  But I go to the "For purchase" section of the software centre and there are only 7 entries.  There's no trace of Uplink (or Darwinia).  I'm running 32-bit natty and have refreshed my software sources, installed all updates, etc.  Is this app not available because I live in Australia?  Is there any way to make it appear so i can spend my $$?

Comment: I seem to remember that if there's only a 32bit version, users of 64 bit Ubuntu will not see it in the list and vice versa.

Comment: thanks @shintoist, I've added the fact I'm using 32-bit ubuntu to the question.

Comment: it is possibly because you are running Natty

Comment: @Roland Taylor: Thanks, it looks like it's not available for Natty.  It doesn't appear on any of my 3 machines running natty, but I've now checked a machine that's still running Maverick and it's available there.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That application is likely not available for Natty (11.04).